# Настройка локального почтового сервера postfix, courier-imap, ssl

Tags: postfix, imap

Настраиваю тестовый почтовый сервер с *postfix* и *courier* в локальной сети.
Всё делал по мануалам найденным в сети и в общем то не сильно отошел от стандартных конфигов.

На сервере (поскольку он тестовый) есть *GUI* и стоит почтовый клиент *Thunderbird*. На сервере есть несколько почтовых ящиков (*linux*-пользователей).

Задача в том, чтобы по локальной сети (c других компов) можно было отправлять письма, а на сервере в *Thunderbird* они бы все отображались.

Отправляться-то они отправляются, но сохраняются только в `/var/mail/$USER`. *Thunderbird* их не видит.

Вариант с локальными аккаунтами в *Thunderbird* отпадает, поскольку в реальности почтовый клиент будет стоять также и не на сервере.

Как реализовать требуемое?

Answer (score 1):

насколько я понял, вы хотите видеть ровно то же, что и пользователи этих почтовых ящиков, подключающиеся по протоколу *imap*.

тогда самым логичным решением будет просто добавить эти ящики в используемой почтовой программе с доступом по тому же самому протоколу.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, всё получилось. Беда возникала при отправке писем. Поскольку я не указал в конфиге postfix использовать формат Maildir они сохранялись в /var/mail/$USER.

Comment: *не указал в конфиге* — а это, собственно, безразлично. главное здесь: чтобы **и** smtp- **и** imap-(pop-)серверы были настроены на использование **одного и того же** типа хранилища.

Comment: сourier использует Maildir как я понял по-умолчанию. Странно, что для postfix нужно это указывать. Получается, что при отправлении письма нужно указывать в каком формате оно должно на сервере сохраниться потом?

Comment: *Странно* — это же разные программы. у каждой — свои «умолчальные» настройки. / *Получается* — нет, не нужно. более того: просто невозможно.